# Asp Button Click Event Not Firing in aspx view in mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have asp button on aspx view in mvc. When I click on button it's not giving any response

```
<script runat="server">
    private void GetReport(string mode = "")
    {
     ..................
    }
    protected void btnShowReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //This Event Not Firing.
        GetReport("print");
    }

 </script> 

 <form id="form1" runat="server" >
         //This Button Click is not Working
      <asp:Button ID="btnShowReport" OnClick="btnShowReport_Click" runat="server" Text="Get Last Report"  />

 </form>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: This is my aspx view and its page directive is <%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %> @Stephen Muecke

Comment: There is no `runat="server"` in MVC and no code behind events - this is WebForms code

Comment: runat="server" comes after adding asp server control in (aspx view) and i have page load event also which is working but having problem in click event..

Comment: You cannot do this. MVC does not support code behind events (your `btnShowReport_Click` method) or `ViewState`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC, avoid these asp.net controls. Use plain HTML controls or use HTML helpers. One of the purposes of using ASP.NET MVC is to have grater control over the code that gets rendered.

Comment: Actually I want to show crystal report on my page so I cannot show crystal report without CrystalReportViewer (which is asp control).that why I am having to use asp.net control